# Socketio background task not running

Tags: python, socket.io, python-asyncio

I am creating a multiplayer online game, and am using socket io for the game server. Below is my server code

```
import socketio
import time
from aiohttp import web

sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp', cors_allowed_origins='*', async_handlers=True)
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print("connected: ", sid)

@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)

async def background_thread():
    while True:
        print("here")
        sio.emit('message', {'data': 'Server generated event'})
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Starting server")
    sio.start_background_task(background_thread)
    web.run_app(app, port=3000)
```

But the problem is the above code starts up the server but the background task is not running, where am I going wrong?